# How to find edges and faces of polyhedron?

Tags: algorithm, math

I have an array of verticies of polyhedron. How to:

1. check if it is convex?
2. find its edges and faces in the case when it is convex?

Thank you.

Comment: This would be better asked on Google than here, methinks.

Comment: One can build different polyhedra on the same set of vertices.

Comment: @n.m. : But it is well-defined whether the points are vertices of a convex polyhedron, and if so then the polyhedron is well-defined as the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of those points.

Answer (score 3):

Quickhull algorithm is suitable to find convex hull of the point cloud in 3D. If convex hull contains all the points from your array, then you can build convex polyhedron with this point set.

Proper implementation of Quickhull will also find faces of resulting convex polyhedron

Comment: If convex hull contains all the points from your array, then *one of the polyhedra* with this vertex-set is convex.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it will be more accurate

Comment: @user1058588 Imagine cube vertices with additional vertex at the face center. All points belong to convex hull, but you can build nonconvex polyhedron like pencil sharpener

Comment: It doesn't have to be quickhull:  *any* convex hull algorithm will do.  But quickhull is usually very fast (and the worst case is not as easy to provoke as with quicksort).